# How do I get rid of the extras?

Tags: dpkg

I upgraded successfully. Now, when I run this:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

I get this:

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                               3.13.0-24.47                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic                                4.4.0-31.50                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic                                4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic                                4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.47                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic                          4.4.0-31.50                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic                          4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic                          4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         4.4.0.36.38                                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

So my question is: What do I do with all the extra modules? Do I trash them? If so, how? or do I keep them?

Comment: Just a thought... If you are not able to find out how to uninstall a software package on your own yet, maybe you should not yet attempt to remove kernel packages just because you *think* you might possibly gain some minimal performance gain (or a screwed up system).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove them, then try running

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

in the terminal

this can't be undone, so make sure that your system is running okay with your current kernel before attempting to do anything

what you will get from removing these older unused modules is some free MBs

Comment: Byte Commander -- I wanted to remove packages because Ubuntu wanted to install updates. When I told it to go ahead and do so, Ubuntu shot back that there was insufficient hdd space in which to install the updates. FYI I'm a writer, not a programmer. Every time Ubuntu wants me to do something of an administrative sort, I am terrified because I don't know what to do. So I come to these places begging help because I don't know what else to do. It's hard to learn to solve Linux problems when you don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. You weren't born a Linux expert. Jimmy